# IFTTT... sometimes forgets to Trigger

Tags: facebook, rss, if-this-then-that

I'm testing RSS to Facebook. I made 3 different recipe, to see how they appear on a Facebook page. During one day, I saw that when I upgraded my RSS (sometimes), one or more of the 3 recipes didn't post on Facebook page.

Now, the same RSS is giving me these 3 messages:

1. last triggered about 4 hours ago  triggered 3 times
2. last triggered about 2 hours ago  triggered 4 times
3. last triggered about 2 hours ago  triggered 4 times

But if I now perform a "check now" at the first recipe, that "forgot" to post,it awakens and as a miracle posts on Facebook.

Remember that it is not always the same recipe that forgets to post; it can be 1, none or 2...

Is it a IFTTT problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you contacted IFTTT support?

Comment: For that matter, have you looked in the [Activity logs](https://ifttt.com/logs)?

Comment: (Frankly, I'd bet that Facebook is throttling your activity.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a fundamental problem with IFTTT. IFTTT is a free service which works most of the time but is not always reliable.

For example, 
I noticed that after a month, an android trigger occurred, but the IFTTT site listed it as not occurring. This has happened to me for two recipes involving my android phone. How I solved this was to uninstall the IFTTT app on my android phone, then remove the android channel, then install the IFTTT application on my android phone again, and activating the channel. After performing these steps the triggers started "triggering" again.

This Android channel just stopped working again after having no problems with it for several days. IFTTT can be buggy at times. There are paid services which I hear are more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, IFTTT does not seem to be reliable as far as consistent timing, especially concerning RSS. I've had many recipes just not fire at all at some times, and then fire again at other times. It's gotten to the point that I no longer feel confident in relying on IFTTT + RSS and had to build my own system to catch what I needed.